# Using OpenMP in Fortran90 to parallelize an implicit scheme

Tags: fortran, openmp

I'm learning how to parallelize some blocks in Fortran90 for a project that i have and i wonder if it is way to parallelize something like this:

```
.....
do l=n-1,1,-1
         u(l)=u(l)-gam(l+1)*u(l+1)
enddo
.....
```

or like this

```
do l=2,n
....
u(l)=(r(l)-a(l)*u(l-1))/bet
....
enddo
```

As my do statement is using previous or the following value

I tried to use classic !$omp parallel("....") but (as expected)  it does not work

Comment: Your code is intrinsically sequential. You can try recursive doubling, but basically you need a gross rewrite.

Comment: You probably want some different scheme. Either red-black iteration or a tridiagonal direct solver or some other sparse solve algorithm.

Comment: Indeed im trying to resolver a tridiagonal matrix

Comment: If you can solve multiple of these matrices at once in parallel, not just one big, then you can use serial direct solvers from any library. Anyway, there are libraries for this task, or even relatively short subroutines, do not reinvent the wheel. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Linear_Algebra/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm#Fortran_90